# Windows Phone: How do I exclude columns/properties in SQLite-net?

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8, sql-server-ce, sqlite-net

If I use SQL Server CE for windows phone I can select which properties of a class map to database tables. This allows me to have abstract properties on a class.

for instance

```
[Table]
public class MyClass
{
    // this property is written to the database
    private int _ItemId;

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, DbType = "INT NOT NULL Identity", CanBeNull = false, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int ItemId
    {
        get
        {
            return _ItemId;
        }
        set
        {
            _ItemId = value;
        }
    }

    // abstract class. obviously this just an example. the real code checks for 11. =)
    // under SQLite, it looks like this will get stored in the db?
    public bool IsItemIdSeven
    {
        get{ return _ItemId == 7; }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to exclude properties from a class definition in SQLite-net? I can't use extensions as some of these properties are used by UI Bindings.

Comment: SQLite doesn't include ORM by itself. What are you using for ORM?

Comment: If you are using [SQLite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) you can use `[Ignore]` attribute.

Comment: Like @AlaaMasoud say in [sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) library in this case you need to use the `SQLite.IgnoreAttribute`

   `[SQLite.Ignore] public bool IsItemIdSeven { get; set; }`

Comment: thanks guys. I am using SQLite-net as an ORM. got a bit confused between SQLite itself and SQLite-net. If one of you submits this as an answer I'll accept it. I'm also updating the question to eliminate confusion

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using [SQLite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) you can use `[Ignore]` attribute

Comment: Alaa Im having problems with Ignore in Windows Phone, do you know of any work around?